# How to search for a string in a saved emails folder

Tags: excel, vba

We are in the middle of a new production line start-up and have a lot of info and emails to communicate. What we want is that all the info is gathered in a folder on the server and that people who need info could search in a textfield to find related subjects. So what I want is to search for a string in email body's but currently I only know how to do this in my own mail box but not how to do it in saved emails in a folder. The code that I have for now is this and is for a Excel macro:

```
Sub FindSubjectInEmails()
Dim outlookApp
Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
Dim Fldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Dim olMail As Variant

Dim myTasks

Dim sir() As String

Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set olNs = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Set myTasks = Fldr.Items

For Each olMail In myTasks
If (InStr(1, olMail.Body, "text_to_find", vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
  olMail.Display
  Exit For
   End If
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Where are the email saved? Outlook folder or desktop folder?

Comment: Also do you want to run this from Excel or Outlook?

Comment: The emails are saved in a desktop folder, I would run this from Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMsg As Object
    Dim msgFolder As String, emlFile As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    '~~> Change this to the relevant folder
    msgFolder = "C:\Users\routs\Desktop\Test\"

    emlFile = Dir(msgFolder & "\*.msg")

    '~~> Loop through the folder to work with the emails
    Do While Len(emlFile) > 0
        Set OutMsg = OutApp.Session.OpenSharedItem(msgFolder & emlFile)

        If (InStr(1, OutMsg.Body, "text_to_find", vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
            OutMsg.Display
            Exit Do
        End If

        emlFile = Dir
    Loop

    Set OutMsg = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes perfect, there is just only one mistake :) --> exit for should be exit do.

Comment: In which order the mails are searched, can it be done by email date?

Comment: Oops. Changed it :) If you want to serch for a particular email based on a date then yes you can do it.